# Dynamic allocation of 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

So I define the pointer **x** pointing to **n** integers as:

```
int* x = new int [n];
```

Values of **x** change in a loop. In the end of the loop I store the pointer **x** in a 2D pointer **y** that has been initialized as:

```
int** y = new int* [n];
```

I use the following assignment expression to store the pointer to **x** in the *ith* element of **y**:

```
y[i] = x;
```

Since **x** points to the same part of the memory but the values stored  in **x** keep changing, all the elements in 2D array **y** will get the last values that have been stored in **x** during the last execution of the loop.

**My question**:

Is there anyway I can unlink the **x** from where it has been pointing and make it point to a new part of the memory every time I store its address in **y**? This way **y** stores the address to different parts of the memory hence the history of answers stored in **x** can be retrieved. Also please let me know if this method (if at all possible) is faster than filling up the rows of **y** with **x** in each iteration by looping over its elements.

Comment: You could have x be a new std::array with n int's, and I think that would give you the "unlink" you're after.  And you could allocate n of them to store in another std::array y.  If you wanted to lean toward C, you could just malloc another x array each time you prepared to make another y entry.  But I'd lean toward std::array.

Comment: you're using c++ - consider using a `std::vector` of `std::vector` types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to keep the history of all the values of the array x inside y.

What are you suggesting isn't really possible without filling up the rows of y with x in each iteration.

What you can do is preallocate so you don't have the new allocation inside the loop, you have it before the loop (you will still do a copy thou).

The cost of memory will still be n^2, and so will be the complexity.

```
  // without preallocation
  {
     int** y = new int*[n];
     int* oldx=0;
     for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        int* x = new int[n];
        // migrate old values in case you are modifying just a part of x
        if (oldx!=0)
        {
            memcpy(x,oldx,n*sizeof(int));
        }
        //... do some stuff with x;
        y[i] = x;
        // keep reference to copy in next iteration
        oldx=x;
     }
  }

  // with preallocation
  {
     int ** y = new int*[n];
     // preallocate memory
     for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         y[i] = new int[n];
     }
     int* oldx=0;
     for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {

         int* x =y[i];
         // migrate old values in case you are modifying just a part of x
         if (oldx!=0)
         {
             memcpy(x,oldx,n-sizeof(int));
         }
         // ... do stuff with x
         // keep reference to copy in next iteration
         oldx = x;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As for what is faster, I cannot say... I suggest you try and setup prototypes of each approach. As for re-linking x, you can use:

```
x = new int[n];
```

I hope this helps.